# How can I add a Maven exec task to execute on `mvn test`

Tags: java, testing, maven, exec

I have the following exec task in my pom:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/EnvJasmine/bin/run_all_tests.sh</executable>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This works great when I run

```
mvn exec:exec
```

But I also want it to run when I execute

```
mvn test
```

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 7):

Got it! You add `<phase>` to the execution!

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>Jasmine Tests</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript/EnvJasmine/bin/run_all_tests.sh</executable>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Woohoo!

Comment: Specifically, to execute in the `test` phase, you add a `<phase>test</phase>` binding term into the `<execution>` element.

Comment: Hi, just got into your post.
I have worked out the exec maven plugin to run an external command. This command runs a server for an integration test.
My problem is that maven gets stuck on this command, so I never get to run the test.
I was wondering if some of you guys had figure it out.