# How to execute scripts before and after SureFire test phase

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

When I invoke `mvm test`, I want to execute a `setup.sql` script before Surefire JUnit is invoked and then execute a `teardown.sql` script after.

I know from [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821686/how-can-i-add-a-maven-exec-task-to-execute-on-mvn-test) how to execute scripts during the test phase, but I have no idea how to define this specific sequence of events. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds not like a unit test more like an integration test which means using something different than JUnit and run via maven-failsafe-plugin ...Apart from that you could use [sql-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the surefire plugin but with its sibling the failsafe plugin. They both execute Tests but in different life-cycle phases. The surefire plugin in test and the failsafe plugin in integration-test. See [life-cycle phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) and the [default plugin bindings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings).

The advantage of the failsafe plugin running in the integration test phase is that there are pre- and post- phases.

Since you mention some sql script it seems you want to prepare a database. At that point you are not really doing unit testing anymore but writing an integration test. So using the failsafe plugin makes the most sense here.

Comment: Absolutely agree. The failsafe plugin in combination with separating unit from integration tests via categories looks like the best practice solution. Thank you!