# How do I get maven to run a java class after successful compilation and before unit tests?

Tags: maven

My unit tests run very quickly but depend on a database that takes a long time to build.

I would like to be able to compile my code, run one of the compiled classes and then my unit tests.

I have a class CreateAndPopulateDatabase, it takes a long time to run.

Is this something I would do in a pre-integration-test phase?

Comment: So that means in the end you do not have unit tests you have integration tests. For such things I would recommend to use a integration test framework like TestNg where you can define to run a class before the test/test group etc. and you should name your test like `*IT.java` and run them with maven-failsafe-plugin...

Comment: this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527584/how-to-execute-scripts-before-and-after-surefire-test-phase